# Position Tkinter complex grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making some test with Tkinter and I tried to make more complexity but it doesn't work :

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame1 = Frame(root, bg='blue',width=200,height=200)
frame1.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky="news")
frame1.grid_propagate(0)

frame4 = Frame(frame1, bg='yellow',width=100,height=100)
frame4.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky="news")
frame4.grid_propagate(0)

frame5 = Frame(frame4, bg='orange',width=20,height=20)
frame5.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky="news")

frame6 = Frame(frame4, bg='pink',width=20,height=20)
frame6.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky="news")

frame7 = Frame(frame4, bg='red',width=20,height=20)
frame7.grid(column=0,row=4,sticky="news")

root.mainloop()
```

Why the frame7 is not in the row 4 but in the row 3 ?

Comment: You are just the 3rd OP that asks for the this related topic TODAY. Please do some research before asking.

Comment: @Atlas435 sorry, Yes I know that it was a lot for a day.

Answer (score 0):

`frame7` *is* in row 4. It *appears* to be in a different row because row 2 and row 3 are empty. Empty rows have a height of zero.

Comment: Ok, so what can be the best solution to solve this issue ?

Answer (score -1):

If you don't put anything in a frame, it's size is zero. Therefore yo can not see anything in row=3.

Try to put something in row=3 and it will appear:

```
frame6a = Frame(frame4, bg='black',width=20,height=20)
frame6a.grid(column=0,row=3,sticky="news")
```

Comment: No, the frame will not appear by setting something on the same place as the frame. You need to put it in the frame to reconfigure the size of that frame. Otherwise he dosent need a frame there.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.